# Twitter share button for silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

Have someone a idea how to implement the 'share button of Twitter' with Silverlight: i'm using the framework 4 of c#.

Comment: you should consider changing your name from default userXXX to somethig more personal. It is hard to care about questions from faceles automaton.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you'll have to use the Twitter API. My idea would be to use one of the twitter libraries for .NET found [here](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/libraries).

Comment: Could it be you give me the wrong information. I want someting like the following link like facebook: http://www.xamlblog.com/#/Category/